# Why get_memory_peak_usage() is greater than get_memory_usage()

Tags: php, memory

I'm trying to figure out this: if `get_memory_usage()` prints memory, used by script when this function was called, then every time this memory count should always increase or shouldn't change (actually, this is happening when I'm trying to get this usage multiple times after some lines of my code). And I've noticed that `get_memory_peak_usage()` is greater than the last result of `get_memory_usage()`, and how can it be if `get_memory_usage()` fixes already used memory, so this value can't decrease?

Script:

```
echo "\n" . 'Used: '.memory_get_usage().' bytes';

$array = array("1" => "value", "foo" => "bar",);

echo "\n" . 'Used: '.memory_get_usage().' bytes';
echo "\n" . 'Peak: '.memory_get_peak_usage().' bytes';
```

Comment: There are many things that could cause the memory footprint of a program to go down, for example when garbage collection was run. If the program always consumed memory without ever releasing it, it would become a memory leak issue very quickly.

Comment: Show your test script

Comment: Added test script, I think I got it, as Abion47 said it can happen due to garbage collection.

Comment: Also surely one would expect PEAK usage to be either == to usage or > usage. Wouldn't you

Answer (score 0):

PHP has dynamic memory management that frees memory that is no longer needed.
The currently required memory (get_memory_usage()) changes during the execution of a PHP script. get_memory_peak_usage() always gets the maximum memory required.

Therefore get_memory_peak_usage() is always greater than get_memory_usage().

The memory is also used by PHP statements, functions, classes, etc.
Sufficiently large arrays must be used to demonstrate how memory management works.

Let's look at the following code:

```
function printMemUse(string $comment){
  printf('%s : %dk/%dk<br>',
    $comment,
    memory_get_usage()/1024,
    memory_get_peak_usage()/1024
  ); 
}
function proc1(){
  $arr = array_fill(0,6000,'a string'); 
  return $arr[2000];
}

printMemUse('start');

$arr = array_fill(0,6000,'a string');
printMemUse('first array filled');

proc1();
printMemUse('after function called');

$arr2 = array_fill(0,6000,'a string');
printMemUse('secondarray2 filled');

$arr = null;
printMemUse('first arr set null');

$arr2 = null;
printMemUse('arr2 set null');
```

Output:

```
start : 376k/413k
first array filled : 637k/637k
after function called : 637k/897k
secondarray2 filled : 897k/897k
first arr set null : 637k/897k
arr2 set null : 377k/897k
```

The first value is memory_get_usage() as kByte, the second memory_get_peak_usage() kByte.

Variables in a function are released again after the end. We're just seeing a new maximum (after function called). This memory is then used by the 2nd array. The maximum value does not increase. With the assignment of NULL, the memory for the arrays is also no longer required.

Try a little yourself in the [PHP sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0e1179c886352030bcf6cb8c49c94b0bbe4ff2f2).